# How to calculate the force for the fragments correctly?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I have a wall on which you can shoot cannonballs from a cannon, after hitting, I replace the wall with fragments of it.

How to correctly apply force to the fragments of the wall after being hit?

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("CannonBall")) {
        var fragments = Instantiate(_fragmentsPrefab);
        fragments.transform.position = transform.position;
        gameObject.setActive(false);
        Physics.SyncTransforms();
        var rigidbodies = fragments.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();
        foreach (var rigidbody in rigidbodies) {
            rigidbody.AddForce(collision.relativeForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't work as realistically as I wanted.

Comment: Without any result of what it looks like and what you find wrong with it, it's hard to give any help. "doesn't work as realistically as I wanted" is very subjective. A short gif or something would be helpful.

Comment: I would add force both in the direction the canon was heading (it's velocity pre-collision), and add force away from the canon normalized(fragPos - canonPos). I would then experiment with different weights between those two forces. Try adding some jittering/randomness. Try reducing the added velocities the further away the fragment is from the canonball impact.

Comment: @Charly, var distance = Vector3.Distance(rigidbody, collision.rigidbody);
var t = Mathf.InverseLerp(_radius, 0f, distance);
var force = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, collision.relativeForce, t);
I try with this implementation of decreasing the force as the distance from the fragments increases.

Comment: @Charly, I checked and it turned out to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Charly's solution

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("CannonBall")) {
        var fragments = Instantiate(_fragmentsPrefab);
        fragments.transform.position = transform.position;
        gameObject.setActive(false);
        Physics.SyncTransforms();
        var rigidbodies = fragments.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();
        foreach (var rigidbody in rigidbodies) {
            var distance = Vector3.Distance(rigidbody, collision.rigidbody);
            var t = Mathf.InverseLerp(_radius, 0f);
            var force = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, collision.relativeForce, t);
            rigidbody.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```